# is there a faster way to load jQuery DOM objects than this?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, dom, coldfusion

I got my SessionMgr.cfc working correctly thanks to Ageax. My question now is is a callback handler faster performance than how I am currently doing it? 
The function that populates the showAll is here;

```
<cffunction name="GetShowAllDropDown" access="remote" output="true" returntype="any" returnFormat="json">
        <Cfquery name="qReportShowAll" datasource="#Request.AppPDS#">
            SELECT 0 AS rowValue, 'All' AS rowLabel
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 1 AS rowValue, 'Active' as rowLabel
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 AS rowValue, 'InActive' AS rowLabel
        </Cfquery>
    <cfset showAll = structNew()>
    <cfset showAll = serializeJSON(qReportShowAll)>
    <cfreturn showAll />
</cffunction>
```

here is my master top level function that I use to cascade actions, ShowAll loads Reports, selecting a Report loads Lines, selecting a Line loads the Nodes created for it;

```
function loadShowAllReports() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'cfc/Reports.cfc'
            , type: 'get'
            , async: false
            , dataType: 'json'
            , data: {
                 method: 'GetShowAllDropDown'
            },
          success: function(response) {
              $.each(response.DATA, function(i, row) {
                  // get value of first row as descriptions;
                  var val = row[0];
                  var descr = row[1]
                  //console.log(val);
                  // append new options
                  $('##cboShowAllReports').append($('<option/>', {
                      value: val,
                      text: descr
                  }));
              });
              // initially populate this with default value of session.rShowAll
              $('##cboShowAllReports').val(getValue('rShowAll'));
              // reset reports to match
              loadReports();
              loadReportsActive();
              loadCreateReportsActive();
              loadReportTypes();
              loadCreateReportTypes();
              // preload Line defaults
              loadLinesActive();
              loadLinesActiveSearch();
              loadLinesActiveCreate();
              loadLinesResult();
              loadLinesResultSearch();
              loadLinesResultCreate();
          },
          error: function(msg) {
              console.log('Error');
              console.log(msg);
          }
      });


     $('##cboShowAllReports').on('change', function() {
         // onChange event, update the session
         setValue('rShowAll', $(this).find(':selected').val());
         // then the selected value
         $('##cboShowAllReports').val($(this).find(':selected').val());
         //reset reports on change to match
         loadReports();
     });
 }
```

The preloads are simply creating placeholder dropdowns prior to changing their values specific to what Report 'rID', Line 'lID' chosen. see below;
[image: Slow Loading DOM]
Is there a faster way of loading placeholders and their values and is a callBack function the best way of doing it. I know, ask 3 engineers a question and get 3 different answers that work, and an argument over which one works best. Any advise would be appreciated.TIA

Comment: yes, the script is surrounded by <cfoutput> tags, so to escape # being a special character in coldfusion, you use ##

Comment: Your function to create the showAll variable is inefficient in terms of both processing speed and memory use.  You use a database call to create a dataset so small that you may as well hard code it.

Comment: and how does that detract from the jQuery DOM load? it is 19b and takes 0.0000032s to execute

Comment: Is your query just a sample of how you are getting data?

Comment: yes, and I am curious why the DOM object takes almost 5s to load a simple query.

Comment: Does your query actually query data `FROM` a table or are you just building default values? If it's just making default values, you probably can just build that `JSON` object yourself without making a database connection and going through the other overhead of querying and serializing that known data.

Comment: simple default values to prepopulate a dropdown, I am attempting to integrate jQuery and ajax into my coldfusion development in an effort to create an API that doesnt require reloading the page over and over again for a simple change. I am new to ajax but seasoned in coldfusion. If you have a link or example on how to create a JSON object as a replacement  would love to learn how.

Comment: @BigBear Which part of the code is taking that long to load. And how are you measuring the query execution time?

Comment: the attached image shows two DOMs loading using Firefox Developer Edition 75.0b3 and the Performance Monitoring tool within. I have alot of 'actions' going on for this API and was trying to understand what pieces of ajax were taking longer than others and came across this. There are two DOM loading here loadShowAllReports() that once loaded runs loadReports() by the filter on the first function. Enabling you to see Inactive reports or Active Reports in the second function.

Comment: @BigBear https://trycf.com/gist/f7a76d09e144a719d07d82b016673759/lucee5?theme=monokai Something like that should return a JSON structure for you.

Comment: @Shawn, Thank you.

Comment: @Shawn pretty sure the `returnformat="JSON"` and `serializeJSON()` are redundant and depending upon what version of CF is being used, may actually cause issues.

Comment: @user12031119, ColdFusion2018 Standard Edition

Comment: @BigBear You should be fine then.  Only older versions of CF will have issues using both, but even still, I prefer to choose one or the other.

Comment: it seems to work well calling the ajax using dataType: 'json' and returnFormat="json" is working well, every comment helps me add to my toolbox. =]